# symfony6, select2, ajax and EntityTpe issues

Tags: ajax, symfony, jquery-select2

I have a symphony app where one of the forms has quite a few "select" fields that are defined with the symphony EntityType and populated directly from entities.
This works very well; however, often it is very slow loading a form for editing an entry because of the number of select fields, some of which have many thousands of entities listed in them.
I therefore decided to start using select2 and Ajax calls to only populate the select fields when the user has typed at least 2 characters.
This in itself works great and is very much faster; however, there seems to then be a huge problem with loading the form and submitting I assume because of data transformation issues since select2 wants the defined array with "id" and "text" fields but my fields are defined using EntityType.
I have tried all sort of things with PRE_SET_DATA and PRE_SUBMIT but just cannot get this to work.
Has anybody been able to get select2 and Ajax working with a symphony EntityType field?

Here are some code snippets.

The form field:

```
   ->add( 'series', EntityType::class, [
      'required' => false,
      'label' =>  $this->translator->trans( 'form.field.label.series' ),
      'mapped' => true,
      'class' => Series::class,
      'by_reference' => false,
      'expanded' => false,
      'choices' => [],
   ])
```

The configuration of the select2 field:

```
   const ajaxSelectSeriesUrl = "{{ path( 'series.select_query_ajax' )|escape( 'js' ) }}";

   const initSelectSeries = ( elem = null ) => {
      $( elem == null ? '.select2-series' : elem ).select2( {
         tags: true,
         theme: "avdb",
         maximumSelectionLength: 1,
         minimumInputLength: 2,
         ajax: {
            url: ajaxSelectSeriesUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
               var queryParameters = {
                  q: params.term
               }
               return queryParameters;
            },
            processResults: function ( data ) {
               return {
                  results: data.results,
               };
            },
            cache: true
         },
      } );
   }
```

If I opt in my app to create a new item then the form loads without a problem and when I start typing in the "series" select2 field, all works as it should and I can select an appropriate option. However, as soon as I go to submit the form, things go wrong and I get the error that the field contains an invalid option.
I can only assume that this is because the field is using EntityType so expects an entity whereas the select2 Ajax returns a results array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What "sort of things" have you tried exactly? The problem lies in the fact that you are overriding the `choices` to an empty array so any value you submit is considered invalid (because the possible values are 'none'). You'd have to load the submitted values on `PreSubmit` and modify the form config. So it looks like you could be on the right track...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a post from @Laurynas I managed to solve the problem.

In addition to the code in my original post, I needed to create PRE_SET_DATA and PRE_SUBMIT event listeners that (re-)created the select field, ensuring that the desired entity data is correctly formatted for select2 and inserted into the "choices".

I did this as follows:

```
class AVItemType extends AbstractType
{
    ...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        ...
        $builder->addEventListener( FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [ $this, 'onPreSetData' ] );
        $builder->addEventListener( FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [ $this, 'onPreSubmit' ] );
        ...
    }

    private function getSelect2SingleField( FormEvent $event, int $entityId = 0)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->add( $fieldName, EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' =>  $this->translator->trans( 'form.field.label.series' ),
            'mapped' => true,
            'class' => Series::class,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'query_builder' => function( EntityRepository $er ) use ( $entityId ) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder( 'e' )
                    ->where( 'e.id = :entityId' )
                    ->setParameter( 'entityId', $entityId );
            },
        ] );
    }

    function onPreSetData( FormEvent $event )
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if ( ! $data ) :
            return;
        endif;

        // Series
        if ( $data->getSeries() ) :
            $series = $data->getSeries();
            $seriesId = $series ? $series->getid() : 0;
            $this->getSelect2SingleField( event: $event, entityId: $seriesId );
        endif;

        ...
    }

    function onPreSubmit( FormEvent $event )
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if ( ! $data ) :
            return;
        endif;

        // Series
        if ( array_key_exists( 'series', $data ) ) :
            $seriesId = $data['series'];
            if ( !( $this->seriesRepository->findOneBy( [ 'id' => $seriesId ] ) ) ) :
                $series = new Series();
                $series->setName( $seriesId );
                $this->seriesRepository->addOrUpdate( $series, true );
                $data['series'] = $series->getId();
                $seriesId = $series->getid();
                $event->setData( $data );
            endif;
            $this->getSelect2SingleField( event: $event, entityId: $seriesId );
        endif;

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now when an existing item is edited, the select2 field is correctly populated with the entity data and when an item is saved, the selected entries in the select2 field are also correctly saved/allocated to the item.

Thanks again to [Laurynas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8150882/laurynas)!

Comment: It would be nice for the readers to have the link to the Laurynas answer that pointed you in the right direction. Thank you.